# Show that $f$ has an inverse

Tags: calculus

The function $f$ is given on the interval $[0,\infty)$ by
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x^5+4x^3+3x+1}$$
Show that $f$ has an inverse.

---

$f'(x)=\frac{5x^4+12x^2+3}{2\sqrt{x^5+4x^3+3x+1}}>0$ for all $x$, so $f$ is injective. How do I show that $f$ is surjective?

Comment: What is the domain and range? Both $[0, \infty)$?

Comment: The range should be $[1,\infty)$, apparently

Comment: This was an exam question. The range was not specified, only the domain.

Comment: Injectivity is sufficient to guarantee the existence of an inverse $f^{-1}:f[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$.

Comment: "How do you show that $f$ is surjective?" You cannot show that, unless you know the codomain of the function.

Answer (score 2):

You've shown that $f$ is strictly increasing, which indeed lets you conclude that $f$ is injective on $[0,\infty)$. But this is sufficient to guarantee the existence of an inverse $f^{-1}:f[0,­\infty) \to [0,\infty)$.

Indeed—and this has nothing to do with analysis, just plain old set theory—any function $f:A \to B$ between two sets is surjective onto its image. In other words, $f:A \to f(A)$ is surjective, by definition of surjectivity. If in addition $f$ is injective, then $f:A \to f(A)$ is bijective, and so it has an inverse $f^{-1}:f(A) \to A$.

Now whether you want to compute the range $f[0,\infty) = [1,\infty)$ explicitly is up to you.

Comment: Its image is $[1,\infty)$, but that on its own needs a proof.

Comment: @drhab Sure, but that's not what the question asks.

Comment: I don't understand the set theory argument.. Could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: @CauchytheDog Which part is unclear?

Comment: I see that in a comment the OP states that the range was not specified. So you are right. However, then the question itself (how to prove surjectivity?) does not really makes sense. That can only be proved is the codomain is known.

Comment: @drhab Agreed; this is not a very good question.

Comment: Then how would you answer this question? Maybe I am following the wrong approach.. It's from a Calculus I exam.

Comment: @CauchytheDog I would answer it as I did.

Answer (score 1):

The positive derivative ensures that $f$ is strictly increasing. Also $f$ is continuous and is not bounded. For $y>1=f(0)$ find some $x_1$ with $f(x_1)>y$ and apply the intermediate value theorem on interval $[0,x_1]$ to prove the existence of some $x\in(0,x_1)$ with $f(x)=y$.